# How can I keep Buttons at the same position below a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

In C#, how is the best way to position 2 `Buttons` at the same distance below a `TableLayoutPanel` when a `Form` is resized as well as the same distance from the right of the `Form`?

Here is an image:

[image]

The `TableLayoutPanel` has the `Anchor` set to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`.

Is there a specific `Form Control` that I should use, or does this need to be done via code in the `Form's` resize event?

Comment: First position them manually using designer in suitable places, the set the `Anchor` property of `Button` to `Bottom` and `Right`.

Comment: Thank you. That works 100% exactly as needed.

Comment: To learn more about windows forms layout, take a look at this link: [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx) and this one: [Layout in Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229674(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If your panel is stretching (Anchor: `Left, Right, Bottom, Top`), then you should set your button's Anchor to `Bottom, Right` so it will basically stay in the same place as you resize your form.